# Commands from file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a file and take commands depending on what each line of the file says.
The file looks like this:

```
Add saw cutting tool
Add yen a monetary unit
Add pan a dish
List     


public void Load(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fileName));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(r);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String temp =sc.nextLine();

            **if(temp.startsWith("Add")){
                String word = sc.next().toLowerCase();
                String def = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                Add(word, def);**           

            }else if(temp.equals("List")){
                List();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is printing:

```
Add saw cutting tool Add yen a monetary unit Add pan a dish
```

I want it to print out like:

```
saw cutting tool
yen a monetary unit
pan a dish
```

I know that the problem isn't in the print.  The problem is in the ** above.  Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to find a way to strip the "Add" from your strings, you can do another condition if sc.next.toLowerCase().equals("add)); skip and word is equal to sc.next. This should given you the desired results. Can we see your print method anyways?

Comment: @chrisedwards the add() sends the word and its def into a binary search tree and the list() prints the tree out alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do this way: It might solve your problem:

public void Load(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fileName));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(r);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                String temp =sc.nextLine();

                if(temp.startsWith("Add")){
                    temp = temp.replaceAll("Add ", "");
                    String[] word = temp.split("\\s", 2);
                    Add(word[0], word[1]);       

                }else if(temp.equals("List")){
                    System.out.println("List");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(temp.startsWith("Add")){
    String word = sc.next().toLowerCase().replaceFirst("All", "");
    String def = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceFirst("All", "");;
    Add(word, def);
}
```